# Day of Month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Trying to write a query where I can see the format of a date using the query below

```
select to_date((substr(Key ,8,15)),'yyyymmdd') from Myrules
where LENGTH(substr(Key ,8,15)) = 8;
```

the data looks like this in the Key field

```
AA-FFL-20200706
AA-FFL-20200961
AZ-MDL-20200961
AZ-MGL-4
```

I'm getting the error saying "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month" Any idea what am I doing wrong above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no day **61** in any month I know.

- AA-FFL-202009**61**
- AZ-MDL-202009**61**